# Unknow errors while overriding methods in UFT 12.51

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

Happy weekend to the reviewers :) I am stuck while I am trying to override a method in **`UFT`** for objects like `link`, `Image` & `button`. I get an unknown error during the execution of script.Would be helpful if someone can direct me. Below is my code

```
' Creating Browser description
' "title:=Work Transfer Management System - WTMS"

Set WTMSBrwsr = Description.Create
WTMSBrwsr("title").Value = "Work Transfer Management System - WTMS"


' Creating Page description
' "title:=Work Transfer Management System - WTMS"

Set WTMSPge = Description.Create
WTMSPge("title").Value = "Work Transfer Management System - WTMS"

'Creating link description

set OdescLnk= Description.Create
OdescLnk("Link").value="Engineering Work Placement"
OdescLnk("html tag").value="A"

Browser(WTMSBrwsr).Page(WTMSPge).Link(OdescLnk).fnBtnClick

'function Lib
RegisterUserFunc "WebButton", "fnBtnClick", "fnBtnClick"
RegisterUserFunc "Link", "fnBtnClick", "fnBtnClick"
RegisterUserFunc "Image", "fnBtnClick", "fnBtnClick"

'Function Definition
Function fnBtnClick(objControl)
    'Check if object exists
    If objControl.Exist Then
        'Check if the object is enabled or not
        If objControl.GetROProperty("disabled") <> 0 Then
            'Click on the button
            objControl.Click
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

The errors occurs at `Browser(WTMSBrwsr).Page(WTMSPge).Link(OdescLnk).fnBtnClick`
Could you please help me know if this is a write way to use a method?

Comment: Can you debug the code and check whether `Browser(WTMSBrwsr).Page(WTMSPge).Link(OdescLnk)` exist or not?

Comment: That absolutely works fine.I've tried clicking & highlighting the link as below
`Browser(WTMSBrwsr).Page(WTMSPge).Link(OdescLnk).click`

`Browser(WTMSBrwsr).Page(WTMSPge).Link(OdescLnk).highlight`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script, as every script, is executed from top to down.

When

```
Browser(WTMSBrwsr).Page(WTMSPge).Link(OdescLnk).fnBtnClick
```

is executed, it will look for a registration for that function, but that does not exist, because the code

```
RegisterUserFunc "WebButton", "fnBtnClick", "fnBtnClick"
RegisterUserFunc "Link", "fnBtnClick", "fnBtnClick"
RegisterUserFunc "Image", "fnBtnClick", "fnBtnClick"
```

has not yet been executed.

**So move the `RegisterUserFunc` calls up to the top, and it will work.**

It might also improve the readability of the code if you declare the function before you reference its name in the `RegisterUserFunc` calls, so **better move the function definition to the top as well**.